# Can I travel between Schengen countries on one itinerary?

Tags: schengen, itineraries, novice-travellers

I want to travel to The Netherlands and Finland at the same time but my money is tight.

For example, if my flight to Amsterdam is on December 29 and I return to my country on January 12, can I go to Finland from January 6 to 10? Can I then go back to The Netherlands for my flight on January 12?

Comment: Is this question about cost or feasibility of the proposed itinerary?

Comment: Do you already have the visa or are you asking about whether you can submit such an itinerary when you apply?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about visas, then:

- All countries in the Schengen Area act as one for visa purposes. Once you enter the Schengen Area, you can travel to any other country in the Schengen Area without needing another visa. So you can definitely go to the Netherlands, Finland and back to the Netherlands before leaving as long as your visa is valid for the duration of your whole stay.
- The country you ask the visa from should be the one you are planning to stay the longest in, which in you case is the Netherlands.
- Note however that this is valid if you travel directly between Schengen countries. If you transit through a non-Schengen airport (in the UK for instance), you will be considered as leaving the Schengen Area, and entering again. This means you would need a multiple-entry visa, while if you fly directly from one Schengen state to another (or transit via another Schengen state), a single-entry visa is enough.